# Sometimes Stripe card number placeholder freeze and can't input card element

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-blade

But When run php artisan optimize:clear,card number placeholder can input card element.Do you have any experience about this.and please give me a solution.

Comment: Look for errors in the browser console.  How do you access the Stripe key and secret?  You don't load from env() directly in the view do you?

Comment: when I directly add the stripe key into function,it works.Before was calling the key from .env.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bad idea to access env files in other than the config arrays, because when the config is cached, env is not read and all values return as null.

In your config/services.php file, add a section like;

```
    'stripe' => [
        'key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
    ],
```

This will setup config values corresponding to the env values for STRIPE_KEY and STRIPE_SECRET

then when you want to use the value, `config('services.stripe.key')` or `config('services.stripe.secret')`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I have tried as soon as I saw your comment but it still freeze.Only direct key in Stripe('pk_test_***************') is works.

Comment: Add your code to the question